# Showing that $\Bbb R^3$ is not homeomorphic to $S^3$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I want to show that $\Bbb R^3$ is not homeomorphic to $S^3$.

Now this means I want to show there is no bijective function, $f$, from $\Bbb R^3$ such that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

---

I can't seem to solve this, however some thoughts come to mind:

- If there is no bijective function I am done.
- All bijective functions cannot be continuous(for some reason) and I'm done.

---

For the first one, this seems as though it would be true. $\Bbb S^3$ 'lives in' $\Bbb R^4$ but I suppose it is bounded, whereas $\Bbb R^3$ is a lower dimension space, but it is unbounded. Hmmm.

For the second one, I can think geometrically that we can't wrap $\Bbb R^3$ into a fourth dimensional ball, such that points that are close in $\Bbb R^3$ are still close in $S^4$, but no idea how to make this rigorous.

---

Essentially my problem comes down to: Showing two things are homeomorphic is logically, but showing they are not seems really hard. Thanks

Comment: There is a bijection, as they both have carinality $2^\omega$.  Sadly it requires more work than that.

Comment: Did you learn compactness?

Comment: Algebraic topology is better at these types of questions, for future reference.

Comment: Well the process of chucking out points for both the spaces doesn't kind of work here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$S^3$ is compact, while $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not. Since any continuous function $f:S^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ maps compact subsets of $S^3$ to compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$, it can't be surjective (or else $f(S^3)=\mathbb{R}^3$ is also compact).

Comment: $S^3$ is compact in $\Bbb R^4$, does that matter? Does being compact in $\Bbb R^4$ mean we can call it compact in general?

Comment: @SkiesBurn Compactness is a topologically invariant property of a space, independent of any space it may be embedded in. So if a subspace is compact anywhere (where we of course need to be consistent about the topologies), it is compact.

Comment: Of course, a set is only compact w.r.t. a given topology, but the standard one for $S^3$ is the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Adding to mathmax's point, the topologies the sphere inherits from any Euclidean space it sits in will be homeomorphic.